# Cannot permanently change locale on 16.04 server

Tags: server, 16.04, locale

I have setup a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 server, but when I attempt to permanently change the locale settings, it fails and reverts back to the POSIX locale.

Typing `locale` yields the following:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

To my knowledge, this means that no locale has been set at all, as the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale) states POSIX is the "*fall-back, ASCII encoding, same as C*".

To ensure the locales `de_AT.utf8` and `en_US.utf8` were present on my system, I ran `locale -a`, which yielded:

```
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
de_AT.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
```

**Please note the inconsistencies with `C.UTF-8`, but `de_AT.utf8`!** What further worries me is that POSIX is the third entry, while on a different, working system, it's last of the list.

In order to change my language to `en_US.utf8`, I typed `sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.utf8`. The `locale` command still showed the POSIX locale. After a logout and new login, `locale` still showed the POSIX locale. After a reboot, `locale` still showed the POSIX locale.

However, when I type `export LANG=en_US.utf8`, it works temporarily, but only until logout. As such, I am pretty certain that the locales were generated correctly.

I am out of ideas. I tried regenerating all locales, but it looks as if `/etc/default/locale` is simply being ignored.

For the sake of completion, `/etc/default/locale` only contains the line `LANG=en_US.utf8`

**UPDATE://** I tried running `sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, and `localectl` also showed me that it set the locale, but even after a reboot, `locale` still shows POSIX and non-ASCII characters are still not rendered correctly.

Comment: `/etc/default/locale` is read by PAM. Did you possibly disable PAM?

Comment: Did you try `systemd` way : `localectl set-locale LANG=C.UTF-8` ?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Not that I would be aware of. How can I check?

Comment: @EdiD I tried, rebooted, but no change

Comment: Not sure. PAM should be enabled on a fresh install, and if you haven't changed anything in `/etc/pam.d`, it should work. But as a hack for now you may want to create `/etc/profile.d/mylocalesetting.sh` and add the line `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson It just cures the symptoms instead of the actual cause. I'll do a fresh install soon and then see if the problem persists. If so, I'm gonna file a bug in launchpad

Comment: Wise decision. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer was indeed PAM-related, as Gunnar Hjalmarsson mentioned in a comment. PAM was disabled via `sshd_config`, although I honestly do not remember doing so myself.

To summarize: If `/etc/default/locale` seems being ignored, check if PAM is enabled.

Answer (score 10):

What I eventually did is a combination of above techniques

I've first done

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

and chosed english, utf8, then:

```
localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

Also edited
**/etc/default/locale**
to look like:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

And after reboot, when I type **locale** it now looks like this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

And no more warnings...

Answer (score 6):

Run the following commands:

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locale
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
reboot
locale
```

Comment: Didn't work. `locale` still shows POSIX for everything

Comment: I assume you have been root for running those commands? I'm not trying to offend, just want to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, of course. There were no error messages or anything similar.

Comment: did you mean locales?

Comment: I'm doing this and it seems to be "dpkg-reconfigure locales" then everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

In deploying some new 16.04.5 VMs, I ran into this exact problem, but with `xrdp` instead of SSH. I solved this by adding the following to `/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

If you are sensitive to additional languages and cultures across login methods, you could put this in `/etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman` (or another PAM configuration file) instead. This may be why it isn't there by default? This is in the following PAM configurations by default on our new VM installations:

cron, lightdm*, login, polkit-1, sshd, su, and sudo.

Hope this helps someone with this problem given login methods other than SSH.

Does anyone know best practices for PAM configuration/modification of common-*?
If there's a better way to get this going it would be good to get that down.